# Is this PC Spec recommends for Win 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, hardware-rec

I have ran the windows 7 uypgrade advisor report and it says it meets everything to run win 7, but I want to be sure that it not only runs it, but runs well as it will be used for image editing (photoshop, lightroom)

```
CPU:    Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.80GHz
Memory: 3.3 GB
Running: XP Pro 32bit
```

Will this be okay to run win 7 home premium on for over a year or would it be better idea to fork out for a better computer?

Comment: It'll run it fine, but if you want it fast in Photoshop/Lightroom then you really need a newer multi-core processor and more RAM.

Comment: Have a look at where your CPU falls on http://www.cpubenchmark.net/ and think if you need a computer upgrade. Newegg has deals for $200-300 for a decent computer that would greatly exceed those specs. You can technically run it on that machine, but it will be painfully slow. Even general web browsing will seem rather laggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your system will run Windows 7. Will it run well? No.

For photoshop and Lightroom use, you'll definitely want at least a dual core and 4GB of RAM. Lightroom can use a fair bit. Rendering images will be timely unless you upgrade also.

Remember, there are minimum requirements for windows, but that does not mean their optimal

Comment: OS Minimum requirements are a joke, all that means is the windows installer will allow you to install it on that hardware.

Answer (score 1):

If that P4 has Hyper-Threading (HT), it's OK. I have a Pentium D 950, 3GB RAM running Windows Vista Business 32bit from 2007, with no issue. Windows 7 should be faster than Vista.

If your CPU doesn't have HT, than the experience will not be so good, especially if an application consumes all of the core's time. In this case I recommend a HW upgrade.

Comment: HT on early P4 CPUs is basically useless, due to bugs in the implementation. (One virtual core can evict a cache line the other virtual core needs, leading to livelock and terrible performance.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sure was a buggy implementation, i always disabled HT in the bios on P4's.

Answer (score 0):

If that processor is single core, and you experience the same as I did with my Pentium 4 2.8GHz, then it will run, but slowly. I've tried Windows 7 on my old HP with the same processor, and even with hyper-threading enabled it was pretty slow. But I must also tell you that the hard drive of that computer wasn't in a perfect condition anymore (actually none of the components were), so I'm not sure.

On another note, why would you *want* to switch to Windows 7? I know everyone says it's that much better and stuff like that, but just think about it; What exactly is the difference for most people between Windows XP and Windows 7? The bling-bling aero interface? If you want performance, and you don't have any special reason to switch to Windows 7, I'd recommend you just stick with Windows XP.